# Android - play sound on button click - Force Close

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, development-environment

I am trying to write an app that will play a sound clip when an image is clicked. The clip is about 1 second long. Whenever the app is opened it force closes. Here's my coding. Why does it force close?

Main Activity

```
package com.jeremy.vroom;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button zero = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnZero);
        zero.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {     
                new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.rev);   
                        mp.start();
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activitymain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnZero"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/uro5" 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc" ></ImageView>
```

Log

```
08-03 17:21:29.156: D/AndroidRuntime(272): Shutting down VM
08-03 17:21:29.156: W/dalvikvm(272): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jeremy.vroom/com.jeremy.vroom.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at com.jeremy.vroom.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-03 17:21:29.298: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  ... 11 more
08-03 17:21:32.588: I/Process(272): Sending signal. PID: 272 SIG: 9
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
ImageView zero = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnZero);
```

instead of

```
 Button zero = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnZero);
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Couldnt figure out why a regular button wasnt working.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
Button zero = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnZero);
```

to

```
Button zero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnZero);
```

see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your XML, you've declared btnZero to be an ImageView, while in the code you reference to it as a Button. This results in your ClassCastException. Try using:

```
ImageView zero = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnZero);
```

instead of

```
 Button zero = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnZero);
```